# How to convert an array of chars to an array of hex values?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, hex, converters

```
cout << "Enter a string" << endl;
cin.getline(str, 100);
char* point;
point = strtok(str, " ");
while (point != NULL){
    cout << point << endl;
    point = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
hexstr[i] = ("%hX ", str[i]);
```

Hey, my program needs to be able to convert user inputted chars to hexadecimal numbers for example "a" should become "61". It also needs to be able to convert the hex back into the original sentence, however, i am stuck with the conversion and the other documentations of this I have found didn't work. Currently, when I try to output the values of hexstr[] it outputs the characters but not the hex, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont really understand the question, but maybe this helps: [`std::cout << std::hex << 42;` prints `2a`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

Comment: `("%hX ", str[i])` is equivalent to `str[i]`. Google the "comma operator".

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer, even though I will not answer your question directly. The thing is that I believe we have a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here and imho you should rethink if you really need to do that "conversion", after all you just need a different representation of the exact same value that you already have available.

Consider for example this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char x = 'a';
    char y = 97;
    char z = 0x61;
    if (x == y) { std::cout << "I am not sure if ";}
    if (x == z) { std::cout << "you need to ";}
    if (y == z) { std::cout << "convert anything ";}
    std::cout << "because (char)"  <<       x  
              << "==0x" << std::hex << (int)x 
              << "=="   << std::dec << (int)x;
    return 0;
}
```

It will print

```
I am not sure if you need to convert anything because (char)a==0x61==97
```

However, if you really want the hex, then the easiest way I can think of is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    char x = 'a';
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << (int)x;
    std::cout << stream.str();
    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
61
```